# Cabal: can't find source for xxx_h in dist/build/autogen

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to install http://open-projects.net/~shahn/darcs/H3D/ but I get the following error message:

```
cabal: can't find source for Horde3DUtils_h in src, dist/build/autogen
```

And I am not sure what it tries to tell me. Does it mean that it can not find the .h file?

He also uses `import Horde3DUtils_h` in his files. Is this correct?